# How to run an ignite app in an android device connected to laptop with a cable?

Tags: react-native

I am trying to run an ignite app in my android phone. I ran this command:

```
npx react-native run-android
```

But it gave these errors:

info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
Jetifier found 1226 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 2 workers...
info Starting JS server...
info Installing the app...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'E:\BOP\react-native projects\SmartCope-git.bop\SmartCope March 18\smartcope-frontend\node_modules@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\native_modules.gradle' line: 206
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating script.

  > Calling `[node, E:\BOP\react-native projects\SmartCope-git.bop\SmartCope March 18\smartcope-frontend\node_modules\react-native\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\bin.js, config]` finished with an exception. Error message: groovy.json.JsonException: Unable to determine the current character, it is not a string, number, array, or object

  The current character read is 'E' with an int value of 69
  Unable to determine the current character, it is not a string, number, array, or object
  line number 1
  index number 0
  Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, scandir 'E:/BOP/react-native projects/SmartCope-git.bop/SmartCope March 18/smartcope-frontend/android/app/build/intermediates/signing_config/debug/out/signing-config.json'    at Object.readdirSync (fs.js:921:3)    at GlobSync._readdir (E:\BOP\react-native projects\SmartCope-git.bop\SmartCope March 18\smartcope-frontend\node_modules\glob\sync.js:288:41)    at GlobSync._readdirInGlobStar (E:\BOP\react-native projects\SmartCope-git.bop\SmartCope March 18\smartcope-frontend\node_modules\glob\sync.js:267:20)    at GlobSync._readdir (E:\BOP\react-native projects\SmartCope-git.bop\SmartCope March 18\smartcope-frontend\node_modules\glob\sync.js:276:17)    at GlobSync._processReaddir (E:\BOP\react-native projects\SmartCope-git.bop\SmartCope March 18\smartcope-frontend\node_modules\glob\sync.js:137:22)    at GlobSync._process (E:\BOP\react-native projects\SmartCope-git.bop\SmartCope March 18\smartcope-frontend\node_modules\glob\sync.js:132:10)    at GlobSync._processGlobStar (E:\BOP\react-native projects\SmartCope-git.bop\SmartCope March 18\smartcope-frontend\node_modules\glob\sync.js:380:10)    at GlobSync._process (E:\BOP\react-native projects\SmartCope-git.bop\SmartCope March 18\smartcope-frontend\node_modules\glob\sync.js:130:10)    at GlobSync._processGlobStar (E:\BOP\react-native projects\SmartCope-git.bop\SmartCope March 18\smartcope-frontend\node_modules\glob\sync.js:383:10)    at GlobSync._process (E:\BOP\react-native projects\SmartCope-git.bop\SmartCope March 18\smartcope-frontend\node_modules\glob\sync.js:130:10)
  ^. Output: Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, scandir 'E:/BOP/react-native projects/SmartCope-git.bop/SmartCope March 18/smartcope-frontend/android/app/build/intermediates/signing_config/debug/out/signing-config.json'    at Object.readdirSync (fs.js:921:3)    at GlobSync._readdir (E:\BOP\react-native projects\SmartCope-git.bop\SmartCope March 18\smartcope-frontend\node_modules\glob\sync.js:288:41)    at GlobSync._readdirInGlobStar (E:\BOP\react-native projects\SmartCope-git.bop\SmartCope March 18\smartcope-frontend\node_modules\glob\sync.js:267:20)    at GlobSync._readdir (E:\BOP\react-native projects\SmartCope-git.bop\SmartCope March 18\smartcope-frontend\node_modules\glob\sync.js:276:17)    at GlobSync._processReaddir (E:\BOP\react-native projects\SmartCope-git.bop\SmartCope March 18\smartcope-frontend\node_modules\glob\sync.js:137:22)    at GlobSync._process (E:\BOP\react-native projects\SmartCope-git.bop\SmartCope March 18\smartcope-frontend\node_modules\glob\sync.js:132:10)    at GlobSync._processGlobStar (E:\BOP\react-native projects\SmartCope-git.bop\SmartCope March 18\smartcope-frontend\node_modules\glob\sync.js:380:10)    at GlobSync._process (E:\BOP\react-native projects\SmartCope-git.bop\SmartCope March 18\smartcope-frontend\node_modules\glob\sync.js:130:10)    at GlobSync._processGlobStar (E:\BOP\react-native projects\SmartCope-git.bop\SmartCope March 18\smartcope-frontend\node_modules\glob\sync.js:383:10)    at GlobSync._process (E:\BOP\react-native projects\SmartCope-git.bop\SmartCope March 18\smartcope-frontend\node_modules\glob\sync.js:130:10)
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 5s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#android-development-environment. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

How to solve these errors and run the ignite app in my phone connected to my laptop with a cable?

Answer (score 0):

Speaking about a connectivity to the Ignite cluster, most likely thin clients are the only option available for mobile devices: https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/thin-clients